# Unpack different types of data packet

Tags: python-3.x, udp, unpack

I have a UDP stream with length of 31 bytes(little endian). The data is not only one type, it's mixed with float,int etc. I'have achieved to read data as ascii. I have converted it to hex, and now I'm trying to parse the data and convert it to the right data format. Here down is the related part of the code;

Receiving packet;

```
import socket
port = your_port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print("waiting on port:", port)
#while 1:
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print(data)
>>b'\xff\xff\x02\x004i\xcaF\x02\x004i\xcaF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\xb3\xa2Bd\x8c\x0f\xbf\x00\x00\xff\x00\xd5\xe6'
```

this data is in ascii format, so I'm converting it too hex;

```
dh = codecs.encode(data, 'hex')
print(dh)

>>b'ffff02003469ca4602003469ca460000000000000000002db3a242648c0fbf0000ff00d5e6'
```

now, I have hex data. I had to convert it to little endian format and after unpack it according to the map. Here is a part of the map: unsigned 16 bit, unsigned 16 bit, single precision IEEE floating(32 bit), single precision IEEE floating(32 bit),...and goes on.
I have read the struct class, as I understood struct.unpack should work. What I have tried so far and couldnt get any result is written down,

```
c = struct.unpack("<HHff....", dh)   # just for the first 4 element written above
```

getting this error;

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length x
```

Any idea and help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. [construct](http://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) library is doing it pretty well. 
Here is the solution;

```
import socket
import struct
from construct import *


port = your port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print("waiting on port:", port)

data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

c = Struct("a"/Int16ul, "b"/Int16ul, "c"/Float32l, "d"/Float32l,....)

x = c.parse(data)

print(x)
```